# Puppeteer returning Object with number as key and empty object as value

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

So, I was working on a web scraper and I need to return an array of links, for that:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const URL = 'SOME_URL';

const SELECTOR = 'SOME_SELECTOR'

const app = async () => {

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(URL,{waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    

    await page.waitForSelector(SELECTOR);

    let content = await page.evaluate(()=> {
      
      let episodes = document.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR);
      return episodes;
    })

    console.log(content)
    await browser.close()
  }catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }


}
```

And I'm getting this as output,

```
  {
  '0': {},
  '1': {},
  '2': {},
  '3': {},
  '4': {},
  '5': {},
  '6': {},
  '7': {},
  '8': {},
  '9': {},
... so on
    }
```

Any pointers why is it happening, I tried with other selectors and even on other URL as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `page.evaluate()` can only transfer serializable values (roughly, the values JSON can handle). As `document.querySelectorAll()` returns collection of DOM elements which are not serializable (they contain methods and circular references), each element in the collection is replaced with an empty object. You need to return either serializable value (for example, an array of hrefs) or use something like `page.$$(selector)` and `ElementHandle` API.

Answer (score 0):

You want evaluateHandle:

```
await page.evaluateHandle(() => [...document.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR)])
```